# why output is different for map function when using list and tuple on map object?

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
def new(a):
    return a*a

x=map(new,[1,2,3,4,5])
print(x)
print(list(x))
print(tuple(x))
```

output is

```
<map object at 0x03717298>
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
()
```

why we are getting output as empty tuple with list(x)?

```
def new(a):
    return a*a

x=map(new,[1,2,3,4,5])
print(x)
# print(list(x))
print(tuple(x))
```

output is:

```
<map object at 0x009E71D8>
(1, 4, 9, 16, 25)
```

the above code gives the tuple as the answer when we are not using list.

Comment: `map` objects are iterators, when you use `list(x)` on it, it *consumes* the iterator, if you try to iterate over it again, like `tuple(x)` it will be empty. Switch the order and you'll see

Comment: Once you've iterated the `map` object once (`list(x)`), it is exhausted, so when you try to iterate it again (`tuple(x)`) there are no values left. You need to re-create the object to use it again.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was hunting for an appropriate dupe, do you know one?

Answer (score 0):

becuase `map` is not a `list`, it is an `iterator`. An `iterator` is something you can apply `for` loop on and get values one by one. So you need to iterate over it to get values from it one-by-one. The `list()` function does the same for you!
You should use:

```
def new(a):
    return a*a

x = list(map(new,[1,2,3,4,5]))
print(x)
```

Similar to `list()`, the `tuple()` function iterates over it to return a `tuple`

```
def new(a):
    return a*a

x = (map(new,[1,2,3,4,5]))
print(tuple(x))
```